# how to send message from angular feature component to electron main process via IpcRenderer in electron desktop application

Tags: angular, electron

I have created angular 8 and electron desktop application. When I am sending a message from the root component to main.js file of electron via ipcRenderer it is working fine. But when I am sending a message from a newly generated component to main.js file it is throwing an error of  "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined".

*Below is my write.component.html*

`<button (click)="write()">Click me</button>`

*my write.component.ts file*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IpcRenderer } from 'electron';
export class WriteComponent implements OnInit {
  public ipcrenderer: IpcRenderer
  ngOnInit() { }

  write() {
    this.ipcrenderer.on('message-to', (event, arg) => {
      console.log("message-to" + arg)
    });
    this.ipcrenderer.send('message-from', 'hellooooooooooooo')
  }
}
```

*my main.js file*

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");
const http = require('http')
let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true
    })
  );
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
ipcMain.on('message-from', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)
  console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++" + arg)
  event.sender.send('message-to', "world");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line `public ipcrenderer: IpcRenderer` You are declaring a variable with type `IpcRenderer`.

But you do **not** assign any value to that variable. So it is expected for that to be `undefined` or `null` or such kind of things.

So you should assign a value to it **OR** the value should be injected from the constructor of the newly generated component.

Maybe you can show me the codes in the root component.